# Retrieving an array of rows from a table for specific columns only (PHP/SQL/Laravel)

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have generalized my code for the purpose of this question.

Lets say I have a 4 models which relate to a different table in my DB

```
Models: ObjectType1, ObjectType2, ObjectType3, AllObjects
Tables: object-type-1, object-type-2, object-type-3, all-objects
```

The AllObjects model contains a function getRowsFromTable which takes in a table name(object-type-1 | object-type-2 | object-type-3). It also contains a function called getSpecificColumns which takes in a table name as well.

all-objects table is formatted as follows:

```
id | name | p1 | p2 | p3 | p4 | p5 | p6 |created_at 
---|------|----|----|----|----|----|----|-----------
1  |elem-1|  x |  x |  x |null|null|null| date1 
2  |elem-2|  y |  y |  y |null|null|null| date2
3  |elem-3|null|null|null|  z |  z |null| date3
4  |elem-4|null|null|null|null|null|  w | date4
```

object-type-1 as follows:

```
id | name | p1 | p2 | p3 |created_at 
---|------|----|----|----|-----------
1  |elem-1|  x |  x |  x | date1 
2  |elem-2|  y |  y |  y | date2
```

object-type-2 as follows:

```
id | name | p4 | p5 |created_at 
---|------|----|----|-----------
1  |elem-3|  z |  z | date3
```

object-type-3 as follows:

```
id | name | p6 |created_at 
---|------|----|-----------
1  |elem-4|  w | date4
```

Functions in the AllObjects model:

```
public static function getSpecificColumns($tableName){
    $columns = Schema::getColumnListing($tableName);
    $removeColumns =  ['id', 'created_at'];

    foreach($removeColumns as $needle){
        $key = array_search($needle,$columns);
        unset($columns[$key]);
    }

    return $columns;
}

public static function getAllRowsFromTable($tableName){
    $columnsUsed = AllObjects::getSpecificColumns($tableName);
    if($tableName = "object-type-1"){
        $allRows = ObjectType1::select($columnsUsed)->get(); //This is where my problem is
    }
    else if($tableName = "object-type-2"){
        $allRows = ObjectType2::select($columnsUsed)->get(); //This is where my problem is
    }
    else if($tableName = "object-type-3"){
        $allRows = ObjectType3::select($columnsUsed)->get(); //This is where my problem is
    }
        return $allRows;
    }
```

My question is, how do I write the query to obtain a multidimensional array of the specific rows necessary for the table requested?

For example, if the $tableName passed in was "object-type-1", I would want to return an array $allRows where:

```
$allRows[0] = ['name' => "elem-1", 'p1' => "x", 'p2' => "x", 'p3' => "x"]
$allRows[1] = ['name' => "elem-2", 'p1' => "y", 'p2' => "y", 'p3' => "y"]
```

I tried:

```
$numColumns = count($columnsUsed);
$index = 0;

$allRows = ObjectType1::select(
foreach($columnsUsed as $column) {
    echo "'" . $column "'"; 
    $index++;

        if($numColumns > $index)
            echo ",";
})->get();
```

but it doesn't allow the foreach loop inside the 'select' statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectType1::select("'".implode("','", $columnsUsed)."'")->get();
```

implode() does pretty much exactly what you are doing with that foreach loop there, should save you some hassle.